# Windows's AutoHotkey. How do I see the script(s) currently running?

Tags: windows

Charity I volunteer for got a freebie - old PC from the office environment, with windows 7 OS.

Based on the task manager, and icon in the tray, there is an AutoHotkey script(s) running. I'm curious what it is, my guess is - it could be a virus or keylogger type of script to monitor employees.

I can't find an option thru GUI to see the location or display currently running script(s) though...

Comment: Just format and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

There would need to be a startup item running a AHK extension script, or a file in the current users "Documents" directory named "AutoHotkey.ahk" You can use the sysinternals tool to check startup items, or check in that location.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

All of that being said to answer the question, you should NEVER try to use a PC from another organisation without cleaning it up first. For your security and the previous owner's security, format/re-image it.